# Transition from one agent to another in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Is it possible to set up a connection between two different agents inside one project? I mean if for example I have one main agent where the greeting and basic intention detection happens, and based on some trigger I want to route user to another agent that is responsible for some authentication for example and than route user back to initial main agent?

I know that this type of transition is not expected inside the Dialogflow CX, however maybe there are some hacks how to do it?